# Prove that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\sum_n a_n x_n$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, alternative-proof

So, here's a nice little result that I deduced using the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) from functional analysis, but I'm wondering if there's a more elementary approach:

> **Fact:** Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with $a_n > 0$ and $a_n \to \infty$. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ with $\sum |x_n| < \infty$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n$  diverges.

I'm thinking there may be a relatively easy to construct sequence $x_n$ here, but I myself can't think of any.  The reason that I know this must hold is that the map $(x_n) \mapsto (a_n x_n)$ is an unbounded operator from $\ell^1$ to $\ell^\infty$ with a continuous inverse defined over the image, but this provides me with no intuition as to how a suitable $(x_n)$ should be constructed.

Comment: One can obtain an $x_n\downarrow 0$ constructively but I don't know how to improve this result.

Comment: @CalvinKhor you might like `\searrow`, i.e. $\searrow$.  And see the answer below, if you haven't already.

Comment: can't edit any more :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $k_n$ such that $a_{k_n}\geq 2^n$.

Define $x_{k_n}= a_{k_n}^{-1}$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Well, that is indeed a relatively easy construction.  Very nice.

Comment: dammit I logged in just to find out someone beat me to it :)