# $\sum a_{n}=\infty$. P T there is $b_{n}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n}=0$ and $\sum a_{n} b_{n}= \infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that there exists a sequence of positive real numbers $b_{n}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}=0$ and $\sum a_{n} b_{n}= \infty$.

My attempt:

If possible suppose that there is a sequence $b_{n}$ convergese to 0 and $\sum a_{n} b_{n}$ is also convergent.

This implies, given $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer N such that $\sum_{n=p}^{n=q} a_{n} b_{n} <\epsilon$ for $q\geq p\geq N$.

Summation by parts 
 $|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q} a_{n} b_{n}|$=$|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q-1} A_{n} (b_{n}-b_{n+1})+A_{q}b_{q}-A_{p-1}b_{p}|< \epsilon$.
We know that $b_{n}$ is bounded, so it is bounded by K.

Now,   $|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q} a_{n} b_{n}|=K|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q-1} A_{n} +A_{q}-A_{p-1}|< \epsilon$.

This implies $|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q} A_{n} +A_{q}-A_{p-1}|< \frac{\epsilon}{K}$.
This is a contradiction because of $\sum a_{n}=\infty$.

Is there is any mistake in this proof?

Comment: Your statement $|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q} a_{n} b_{n}|=K|\sum_{n=p}^{n=q-1} A_{n} +A_{q}-A_{p-1}|< \epsilon$ is wrong.

Comment: Also there's something clearly wrong with your proof: starting with the assumption that $b_n \to 0$ and that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges, you have concluded that $\sum a_n$ must converge.  This is demonstrably false, consider for instance
$$
a_n = \frac 1n, \quad b_n = \frac 1n.
$$

Comment: you didn't use contrapositive in the first line. and your proof in false

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. I agree with your opinion. Any other hint to prove this result?

Comment: Let $_{}$ such that $_{_{}}≥2^{}$

.

Define $_{_{}}=^{−1}_{_{}}$
and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: @kapil the trick from the problem I linked doesn't work, which is why I deleted my comment. Note that there is no reason to believe that we will have $a_k \geq 2^n$ for any $k$.

Comment: @kapil A non-constructive answer following [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1825936/81360) that I linked earlier is that it suffices to consider the continuity of a diagonal linear operator from $\ell^1$ to $\ell^1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can construct a suitable sequence $b_n$ as follows: first, define a sequence of $k_m$ for $m = 0,1,2,\dots$ that satisfies

- $k_0 = 0$
- $\sum_{j={k_{n-1}}}^{k_{n}} a_n \geq m$ for $m = 1,2,\dots$.

Then, define the sequence $b_n$ by $b_n = \frac 1{m(n)}$, where
$$
m(n) = \max\{m \in \Bbb N : n \geq k_m\}.
$$